# Remove inner padding from CheckboxListTile

Tags: flutter

How can I remove the inner padding from a `CheckboxListTile`?
I tried:
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
dense: true,

and they both help, but they don't remove the inner padding between the checkbox and the text

[image]

Here's my code:

```
CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text('Remember me'),
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  dense: true,
                  value: isPrefered,
                  onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => isPrefered = value),
                ),
              )
```

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: @JohnJoe Added code

Comment: maybe create a custom one?

Answer (score -2):

```
ListTileTheme(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
    child: CheckboxListTile(
        secondary: const Icon(Icons.drive_eta),
        title: Text("Your message"),
        onChanged: (bool value) {},
        value: true,
    ),
),
```

Try this